# Running Total + % Of (PivotTable)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table, worksheet-function

I have a table:

```
        Group 0     Group 1     Group 2
Day 1   10          12          9
Day 2   7           5           14
Day 3   12          11          3
...
```

I want to calculate running total for Groups 1 and 2 as % of running total of Group 0:

```
        Group 0     Group 1     Group 2
Day 1       100%    120%        90%
Day 2       100%    100%        135%
Day 3       100%    97%         90%
...
```

A pivot table allows to "Show Value As" *either* running total or % of, but I can't figure out how to have both.

Comment: Added expected result in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt possible even in Excel 2010 (which I don't have) but the values you show are achievable with the PivotTable showing running totals and (if `Day1` is in E4) `=F4/$F4` alongside and copied down and across to suit.

Comment: I hoped for a more elegant solution, but this works. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is good enough, and I've already used your solution. If anyone knows a better way of doing it, they're always welcome to post it here.